# Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' IIS6 Server 2003

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

We are trying to upload numeric data from .xls spreadsheets to our site which then stores the data to our SQL server (Server 2003, MS SQL 2k), however, keep getting this error message:

```
Executing asnDTSupload from WMSSQL
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' 
Server.CreateObject Failed 
/cpsiteadmintools/asn-dts-update.asp, line 129 
800401f3
```

This is line 129:

```
Set oPkg = Server.CreateObject("DTS.Package")
```

Production Environment is Windows Server 2003 Enterprise using IIS6. This same page works in our similar Test environment, however, the only difference is that the test environment has its own SQL Server Instance. The Production environment communicates to a separate SQL2K server on the same network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I would think you need to install/register the DTS Package Object library on your web server. It works on your test box because you already have SQL Server installed on the same machine.

The Microsoft DTS Package Object Library is dtspkg.dll; depending upon your SQL Server version, it should be somewhere in the Tools folder hierarchy.